# How to convert html links?

Tags: python, html, hyperlink

suppose that I download many html pages to the directory

> /path/to/my/dir

the .html pages contain links like :

```
"<a href="http://www.example.com/lessons/firstlesson.htm">first lesson</a>"

"<a href="http://www.example.com/lessons/secondlesson.htm">second lesson</a>"
```

Thanks  to TobSpr , the answer convert them as follow :

```
"<a href="/path/to/my/dir/firstlesson.htm">first lesson</a>"

"<a href="/path/to/my/dir/secondlesson.htm">second lesson</a>"
```

**UPDATE**

but how to deal with this format of links :
    "first lesson"

```
"<a href="../index.htm">index</a>"
```

Using the usual string functions is very difficult , dirty and buggy , So I hope to get another beter way .

Comment: Can't you just use find/replace in Notepad++ or similar? Scripting this seems unnecessary.

Comment: doing this for many many links in each page is impossible ...

Comment: Why? Most editors have the ability to replace all instances of a string across multiple files. In fact, Notepad++ can probably do this in a more robust manner than you will with Python.

Comment: why does `content.replace("http://www.example.com/", "file///path/to/dir/")` not work for you? It would also replace image and include paths

Comment: @TobSpr add your comment as answer so tabebqena can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
content.replace("http://www.example.com/", "file///path/to/dir/")
```

It replaces also the path of includes.